# Why is an object not automatically set to nil when its reference count becomes 0?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, release, reference-counting

In a non ARC Objective C environment, I understand why we have to release an object: to free the memory allocated for it; I understand why we have to set it to nil afterwards (if we are sure nothing else needs the instance / nothing else still has a hold on the object): to avoid dangling pointers.

However my question is, if all objects release their hold on an object, "carInstance" for example, resulting in its reference count going down to 0, why oh why does that Not automatically make it nil?

If reference count is now 0, is the object still usable in any way? Or is this just one of those things we have to do just because that's how not having garbage collection works (can't be, there must be a reason)

Comment: pnizzle is asking about non-ARC environments.

Comment: @SeamusCampbell Whoops, completely misread that!

Comment: you want it _magically_ be `nil`?

Comment: @BryanChen , is there any reason why it can't "magically" be nil when reference count becomes 0 ?... Is my question

Comment: because it is hard (for compiler to implement) and slow

Comment: The relationship a pointer has with an object is "one way". The object has no idea who is pointing to it. Different pointers to the same object also have no knowledge of each other. The behavior you want is why ARC was created.

Comment: @CrimsonChris sounds logical to me. I was also thinking that since a pointer points to a memory location, changing the contents of that location should have nothing to do with changing what the pointer points to (upto you whether you want to change that or not). Am I wrong in my thought ?

Comment: I believe you understand. What you should take away from this is that ARC is amazing and you should almost always prefer it over manual memory management. It's far less bug prone and results in cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the manual memory management model that was used pre-ARC is lightweight and simple.  The behavior you are wishing for is the behavior you get with `weak` pointers under ARC; and it requires extra work by the OS, to track weak pointers and nil them out when the object is reclaimed.  It's doable, clearly, but the cost of implementing it, as well as the computational overhead, wasn't deemed worthwhile until Apple was already rolling out the extra work of implementing ARC.

After an object is deallocated, the dangling pointer is *worse* than useless: it is downright dangerous.  Referencing it while it points to unallocated memory produces an exception; referencing it after it is randomly reassigned to another object or some other memory allocation will typically produce an 'object does not respond to selector' error.